# How to validate if a letter in an array is repeated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

I want to validate that a string within an array is not repeated more than 3 times, that is:

```
let array = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
let array2 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'] <-- Not valid
```

That the code does not continue to work, if the array it receives has values that are repeated those times

Thank you

Comment: please add what does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in combination with [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check if a value only exists an x amount of times.

```js
const array = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'];
const array2 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'];

const isValid = (arr, limit) => {
  return !arr.some((char) => (
    arr.filter((ch) => ch === char).length > limit
    // use the next line for a case insensitive check
    // arr.filter((ch) => ch.toLowerCase() === char.toLowerCase()).length > limit
  ));
}

console.log(isValid(array, 3));
console.log(isValid(array2, 3));
```

Comment: Goes over each element in the whole array and filters it, which is not that good as the array might grow to bigger sizes. Would have been better with a `some(...)` to exit early and be a bit more performant.

Comment: @MauriceNino Good point, i changed it to a `array.some()`

Answer (score 0):

You can count all the letters using reduce and then check those, like so:

```js
let array = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'];
let array2 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'];

const allElementsExistUpToN = (arr, n) => {
  const counts = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el] = acc[el] == undefined ? 1 : acc[el] +1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return !Object.values(counts).some(c => c > n);
}

console.log(allElementsExistUpToN(array, 3));
console.log(allElementsExistUpToN(array2, 3));
```

Comment: Consider renaming `isRepeatedMoreThanN` because it seems to do the opposite...

Comment: True, my mistake @iAmOren

Comment: I also like that you are passing the max count into the function = generalized.
ps. edit the function name so I can up-vote your answer...

Comment: Function name is edited, can't come up with a better one @iAmOren

Comment: How about `allElementsExistUpToN` or 'noMoreThanNRepeats'?
Or, back to `isRepeatedMoreThanN` and remove the `!` from the `return`?
Whatever you chose, put in the `console.log` tests so the code snippet won't break.

Comment: Done - tbh I could also have named it `func` as it shows a concept and not a finished project @iAmOren

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the count of the last string and check the count or reset the count to one.

```js
const
    check = array => array.every(
        (c => (v, i, { [i - 1]: l }) => l === v ? c++ < 3 : (c = 1))
        (0)
    );

console.log(check(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']));
console.log(check(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']));
```